# How to use ' in a single quoted string?

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error

I use the following for a `preg_replace`:

```
$replace = '/[!\/."",#\s\-:?"]+/';
```

For example when I try and add `'` above it gives me an error on the file:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR in .../s.php on line 38

Additionally, is there an easier way to list all of the symbols to be replaced?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR in /home/##/s.php on line 38

Comment: .....and what's the code on line 38?

Comment: Why do you put 3 times the symbol " ?

Comment: I just basically want anything like !"£$%^&*()_+=|\<>.?/~#'@;:{}[]

Comment: Putting `<?php $replace = '/[!\/."",#\s\-:?"]+/'; ?>` into a file and running it on the command line (via `php`) produces no syntax errors.  Please post more code.

Comment: The line mentioned in syntax error messages do only tell you the location where the error occurred but not the location that caused this error. The cause of this syntax error is probably somewhere before that line (missing glosing quote, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of any symbol, try:

```
$replace = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/";
```

The `^` indicates "anything but the following". Add whatever characters you want to allow to the list. It's easier than listing every symbol and having to deal with escaping.

Comment: I use ' print "<a href='".preg_replace($replace, '-', $product->name)."-p-".$product->id.".html'>";' to replace all the stated above once with -. Now however it does not replace them only once, any assistance?

Comment: Add `-` to the list of allowed characters. Put it right at the end of the character class so you don't need to escape it.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: This however leaves spaces in the url, for example Apple iPad 2 Wi-Fi - 3G 16GB White Tablet - MC982NFA-p-110341697.html

Comment: Remove the space from the allowed characters, then. It's quite simple ;)

Comment: Already tried that, however it shows it like this Apple-iPad-2-Wi-Fi---3G-16GB-White-Tablet---MC982NFA-p-110341697.html where it should only replace it with one "-", like this Apple-iPad-2-Wi-Fi-3G-16GB-White-Tablet-MC982NFA-p-110341697.html

Comment: @JackTheJack: You actually have two question. The first question is to solve the syntax error your code produces. The second question is how to create the URL. The first question is a result on the way to solve the second question, but you probably want to ask a second question after you have solved the first. Keep things apart to get better answers. Also improve the writing of your questions so they are more precise (e.g. I added the error message, you should provide these important things firsthand so it's clear what you ask about).

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `'` character as it's also the delimiter of the single quoted string:

```
$replace = '/[!\/.,#\s\-:?"\']+/';
                           ^^
```

Escaping is done by adding `\` in front of it. This is normally logical as you otherwise would have finished the string definition which then leads to a syntax error (PHP is not able to parse your code). See [Single quoted String<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

> Is there an easier way to list all of the symbols to be replaced?

Isn't it easy enough to just list them (as you already do)? So I must admit it's not clear to me what you're actually concerned about so I can't offer something more easy.